# Understanding git and applying to my workflow

Tags: git, github, ftp

I want to use git and I have been reading about it. But I don't want to use github. I work on my windows PC. I have xampp installed and I have a separate folder called Projects. In this folder I keep all my projects. When I start new project I create new virtual host in Apache and add it to windows host file and also create a folder for it in the Project folder.

Basically I work locally. When I finish the project I upload everything to my server via FTP. When I do changes to the project I upload the files that I changed to the server with ftp.

First of all I want to use git to track changes on my local pc. Is that something git does?  or do I have to use github?

And can I use git with my own server which is media temple dv server.

Can anyone explain me little bit better? This makes me so confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are saying, but you'll also have to upload all the git files in the .git folder if you want git to be able to track them later.

Git manages the changes locally through the invisible (to UNIX) .git folder in each of your project directories (or working directory). When you change branches, git is really reaching into this .git folder and making changes to your working directory from there.

Reading up on how git works from the bottom up will help too:
http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can def do what you are saying. i use git all the time just to version control my work without pushing to github. download git and use it locally. Once you 'git init' just 'git add []' and 'git commit -m [message]' but then don't push to any remote (ie. github). github is just an online public repo store if you want your work saved on the cloud as well to either share with others, work with others, or heaven forbid you comp cashes and your work wasn't saved anywhere else. Github only allows you to push public repos for free, however, i use bitbucket.org as well since it allows you to have private repo's for free (sometimes we don't wanna share :)). 
Also try sourceTree as a really cool git gui tool. http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Absolutely.

Git is lightweight, portable, and does not require a network connection for local operation (you can track all your changes locally and never push anything to a remote repo, and Git is perfectly content with that). I use Git for just about everything, from tracking changes on a single file, to tracking large projects. Some of those projects are managed completely locally, and others are synced with remote repositories.

**All** the metadata (commit history, branches, repo configuration, etc) associated with a particular repository is neatly tucked into the `.git` folder, which is created when you run `git init` in a directory. When you run a Git command, Git will look for the nearest `.git` folder (starting in the working directory and working up parent directories until a `.git` folder is found). Git doesn't need any network connection to run, unless you want to use it's collaborative functions (basically, syncing with remote repos).

GitHub is simply a service for hosting remote repositories (distributed version control). It's arguably the most popular, but it's [not the only one](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitHosting). You don't need a service like GitHub for solo projects unless you'd like to publish your project online as open source (private repos are a paid service).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look [BitBucket.org](https://bitbucket.org). It is a "competitor" to github, differing that you can control 5 closed source projects and use other version control tools like Mercurial.

There you will find too a git client (SourceTree) that can help you to use git without use command line.

If you need some simple command line shell, i write some things about it in my [blog](http://macielbombonato.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/utilizando-git-versionador-local.html), but it is in brazilian portuguese.

I hope that this help you.